# Remove a specific line from a file WITHOUT using sed or awk

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I need to remove a specific line number from a file using a bash script.

I get the line number from the grep command with the -n option.

I cannot use sed for a variety of reasons, least of which is that it is not installed on all the systems this script needs to run on and installing it is not an option.

awk is out of the question because in testing, on different machines with different UNIX/Linux OS's (RHEL, SunOS, Solaris, Ubuntu, etc.), it gives (sometimes wildly) different results on each. So, no awk.

The file in question is just a flat text file, with one record per line, so nothing fancy needs to be done, except for remove the line by number.

If at all possible, I need to avoid doing something like extracting the contents of the file, not including the line I want gone, and then overwriting the original file.

Comment: ed or red may give you what you want: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/58027/removing-consecutive-newlines-with-ed

Comment: can you include your awk script in this post. I'm very surprised by your assertion (excepting *maybe* sun 4's (old) awk (not nawk)). Good luck.

Comment: I don't have the awk script that was used originally. This instruction comes from the people who make more money than me...

Comment: Looking at the notes from the original author of parts of the script, it was in fact several of the Sun machines that we use as NIS servers that had the issues. it does not say what version of anything it was that caused the issues.

Answer (score 7):

Since you have `grep`, the obvious thing to do is:

```
$ grep -v "line to remove" file.txt > /tmp/tmp
$ mv /tmp/tmp file.txt
$
```

But it sounds like you don't want to use any temporary files - I assume the input file is large and this is an embedded system where memory and storage are in short supply.  I think you ideally need a solution that edits the file in place.  I think this might be possible with `dd` but haven't figured it out yet :(

***Update*** - I figured out how to edit the file in place with dd.  Also `grep`, `head` and `cut` are needed.  If these are not available then they can probably be worked around for the most part:

```
#!/bin/bash

# get the line number to remove
rline=$(grep -n "$1" "$2" | head -n1 | cut -d: -f1)
# number of bytes before the line to be removed
hbytes=$(head -n$((rline-1)) "$2" | wc -c)
# number of bytes to remove
rbytes=$(grep "$1" "$2" | wc -c)
# original file size
fsize=$(cat "$2" | wc -c)
# dd will start reading the file after the line to be removed
ddskip=$((hbytes + rbytes))
# dd will start writing at the beginning of the line to be removed
ddseek=$hbytes
# dd will move this many bytes
ddcount=$((fsize - hbytes - rbytes))
# the expected new file size
newsize=$((fsize - rbytes))
# move the bytes with dd.  strace confirms the file is edited in place
dd bs=1 if="$2" skip=$ddskip seek=$ddseek conv=notrunc count=$ddcount of="$2"
# truncate the remainder bytes of the end of the file
dd bs=1 if="$2" skip=$newsize seek=$newsize count=0 of="$2"
```

Run it thusly:

```
$ cat > file.txt
line 1
line two
line 3
$ ./grepremove "tw" file.txt
7+0 records in
7+0 records out
0+0 records in
0+0 records out
$ cat file.txt
line 1
line 3
$
```

Suffice to say that `dd` is a **very dangerous** tool.  You can easily unintentionally overwrite files or entire disks.  Be very careful!

Comment: No offense, but in the spirit of using the right tool for the right job, I really hope OP doesn't go with `dd` as a solution.

Comment: No offense taken.  I agree that `dd` is a ***very dangerous*** tool, and its use should be very carefully considered.  Having said that, it is a very versatile tool, and I think the only one so far which can be used to correctly answer the OPs question - i.e. remove the line from the file in-place, without any temporary files.

Comment: The problem with creating a temp file is that the file in question is HUGE (up to 1.9 GB on some systems) and the dir where it lives is actually being exported from an NFS server that shares it to all the machines that need to use the file. That NFS server also enforces quotas on the exported directory. If I try to cp it to the same dir as a temp file, there is a really good chance that it will exceed the quota on a few machines. If it try to cp it to the local machine first, this will mean a lot of network I/O. Yes, I know out setup/topology is insanely complicated. No, I did not design it...

Comment: That said, I think dd is a little too dangerous for this instance. Awesome concept though!

Comment: @user2773624 - Even if you use an edit-in-place method like the `dd` method I outlined, I think you're still going to incur significant network IO, dependent on where in the file the line-to-be-removed is.  Any edit-in-place method will have to read the remainder of the file, and then write it back to the new position, all over the network.  Add to that the fact you have also read through the file while grepping for the line number to remove, then I think you probably won't lose much by copying the file to large/fast/local storage, editing, then copying back.

Comment: This is true. My original idea was to build a command string that I could send to the NFS server with `rsh`, thereby making the filer do all the work. I'm now not so sure. These servers are temperamental at the best of times and I don't want to upset them too badly. They are the main reason that I can't use `sed`. I can send `rsh` to the NFS servers, but I cannot SSH or telnet into them to try and get anything done the easy way...

Comment: @user2773624 - Check out my [second answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19128876/remove-a-specific-line-from-a-file-without-using-sed-or-awk/19147906#19147906) - this shows how to do the in-place editing you need with Tcl instead of dd.  Perhaps you have access to a scripting language such as Tcl?

Comment: "Suffice to say that dd is a very dangerous tool. You can easily unintentionally overwrite files or entire disks." I mean, you can just as easily do that with plain old shell redirection. I think `dd`'s reputation for deleting disks comes from our penchant for giving it root privileges and pointing it at disks.

Answer (score 4):

Try [ed](/questions/tagged/ed). The here-document-based example below deletes line `2` from `test.txt`

```
ed -s test.txt <<!
2d
w
!
```

Comment: my experience with Sun `ed` is that it couldn't read very large files without breaking. Using the `vi`s `ex` mode works about the same way and is only limited to space available where `ex` writes its temp file, which is configurable with :`tmp=/path/to/tmpdir` (or similar, consult your vi doc).

Comment: 'course, one wonders why OP doesn't just search for the actual pattern using *ed* instead of getting the line number with `grep -n`, parsing that out of the grep output, composing `ed` input with it, and passing it to ed.

Comment: When I run this under `strace`, I see a temporary file is created: `open("/tmp/ed.kNTc8I", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_EXCL, 0600) = 3`.  Not so with the `dd` solution I posted.

Comment: @DigitalTrauma, is the temp file in the same ballpark as the original in terms of size?

Comment: @1_CR - Yes.  At least I ran ed interactively `strace ed -s ed.txt` with a 1.2MB file and see a similar-sized file appear in /tmp as soon as ed has started up: `-rw-------  1 user user 1228800 Oct  2 10:16 /tmp/ed.v0fHPp`.  The file disappears once ed is quit.

Comment: The reason being, kojiro, is that I need that line number several more times for other functions, so it just gets dumped into a variable as a string, then I can use the number again just by calling it. Makes my life a lot easier.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it without grep using posix shell builtins which should be on any *nix.

```
while read LINE || [ "$LINE" ];do
  case "$LINE" in
    *thing_you_are_grepping_for*)continue;;
    *)echo "$LINE";;
  esac
done <infile >outfile
```

Answer (score 2):

If `n` is the line you want to omit:

```
{
  head -n $(( n-1 )) file
  tail +$(( n+1 )) file
} > newfile
```

Answer (score 2):

Given `dd` is deemed too dangerous for this in-place line removal, we need some other method where we have fairly fine-grained control over the file system calls.  My initial urge is to write something in c, but while possible, I think that is a bit of overkill.  Instead it is worth looking to common scripting (not shell-scripting) languages, as these typically have fairly low-level file APIs which map to the file syscalls in a fairly straightforward manner.  I'm guessing this can be done using python, perl, Tcl or one of many other scripting language that might be available.  I'm most familiar with Tcl, so here we go:

```
#!/bin/sh
# \
exec tclsh "$0" "$@"

package require Tclx

set removeline [lindex $argv 0]
set filename [lindex $argv 1]

set infile [open $filename RDONLY]
for {set lineNumber 1} {$lineNumber < $removeline} {incr lineNumber} {
    if {[eof $infile]} {
        close $infile
        puts "EOF at line $lineNumber"
        exit
    }
    gets $infile line
}
set bytecount [tell $infile]
gets $infile rmline

set outfile [open $filename RDWR]
seek $outfile $bytecount start

while {[gets $infile line] >= 0} {
    puts $outfile $line
}

ftruncate -fileid $outfile [tell $outfile]
close $infile
close $outfile
```

Note on my particular box I have Tcl 8.4, so I had to load the Tclx package in order to use the ftruncate command.  In Tcl 8.5, there is `chan truncate` which could be used instead.

You can pass the line number you want to remove and the filename to this script.

In short, the script does this:

- open the file for reading
- read the first n-1 lines
- get the offset of the start of the next line (line n)
- read line n
- open the file with a new FD for writing
- move the file location of the write FD to the offset of the start of line n
- continue reading the remaining lines from the read FD and write them to the write FD until the whole read FD is read
- truncate the write FD

The file is edited exactly in place.  No temporary files are used.

I'm pretty sure this can be re-written in python or perl or ... if necessary.

***Update***

Ok, so in-place line removal can be done in almost-pure bash, using similar techniques to the Tcl script above.  But the big caveat is that you need to have `truncate` command available.  I do have it on my Ubuntu 12.04 VM, but not on my older Redhat-based box.  Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

n=$1
filename=$2
exec 3<> $filename
exec 4<> $filename
linecount=1
bytecount=0
while IFS="" read -r line <&3 ; do
    if [[ $linecount == $n ]]; then
        echo "omitting line $linecount: $line"
    else
        echo "$line" >&4
        ((bytecount += ${#line} + 1))
    fi
    ((linecount++))
done
exec 3>&-
exec 4>&-

truncate -s $bytecount $filename
#### or if you can tolerate dd, just to do the truncate:
# dd of="$filename" bs=1 seek=$bytecount count=0
#### or if you have python
# python -c "open(\"$filename\", \"ab\").truncate($bytecount)"
```

I would love to hear of a more generic (bash-only?) way to do the partial truncate at the end and complete this answer.  Of course the truncate can be done with `dd` as well, but I think that was already ruled out for my earlier answer.

And for the record [this site](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Truncate_a_file) lists how to do an in-place file truncation in many different languages - in case any of these could be used in your environment.

Answer (score 1):

If you can indicate under which circumstances on which platform(s) the most obvious Awk script is failing for you, perhaps we can devise a workaround.

```
awk "NR!=$N" infile >outfile
```

If course, obtaining `$N` with `grep` just to feed it to Awk is pretty bass-ackwards. This will delete the line containing the first occurrence of `foo`:

```
awk '/foo/ { if (!p++) next } 1' infile >outfile
```

Comment: or even: `awk '!/foo/||p++' infile > outfile`. But that's not in-place, fwiw.

Answer (score -1):

Based on Digital Trauma's answere, I found an improvement that just needs grep and echo, but no tempfile:

```
echo $(grep -v PATTERN file.txt) > file.txt
```

Depending on the kind of lines your file contains and whether your pattern requires a more complex syntax or not, you can embrace the grep command with double quotes:

```
echo "$(grep -v PATTERN file.txt)" > file.txt
```

(useful when deleting from your crontab)

Comment: The command substitution will put the entire `grep` output into memory (if available), and then paste that entire output onto the `echo` command line.  This will break for input files larger than normal command-line length limit which is unlikely to be larger than a couple of megabytes - not sufficient for the OP.  Not to mention how echo can change output in subtle ways - `printf` would be more reliable