# Using variable inside of sed -i (regex?) bash

Tags: bash, variables, sed

I've looked at the other `sed` pages here and i cannot find one that uses `-i` with a variable in the regex search portion. I am trying to cut out a requested line in the file `myresolv.conf` and by getting its line number. 5 people in my class are all stuck :( 
Any help is awesome

```
line=$(grep -n "$3" ./myresolv.conf | cut -d: -f1)

sed -i "$line"  ./myresolv.conf
```

Comment: do you mean `remove line` when you say `cut out line`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove a specific line from a file WITHOUT using sed or awk](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19128876/remove-a-specific-line-from-a-file-without-using-sed-or-awk)

Comment: i want to use sed dude

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem you want to delete a specific line from a file. You're hopefully getting a single line number in your `line` variable (but beware - if you have multiple lines that match, you're going to get a list of numbers, and that will cause the rest of your process to explode). The problem you have is that the command you are feeding `sed` is simply the line number - you are not specifying anything for `sed` to do with that line number. So, perhaps you want this:

```
sed -i "${line}d" file.txt
```

If I've misunderstood your question, and you're not wanting to delete that line, but simply print it, then replace the `d` with `p`...

Comment: I want to delete the line but this isnt working for me, i get         sed: -e expression #1, char 2: unknown command: `
'

Comment: Perhaps your `line` variable contains something other than a number, then...? Or you have a version of `sed` that wants an argument to `-i`, like `sed -i bak "3d" file.txt`...

Answer (score 1):

I assume, you mean `remove line` when you say `cut out line`.

Try using `grep` with `-v` option. I believe you don't need `sed` here.

```
grep -v "$3" ./myresolv.conf
```

Or if you want to delete line in the file itself

```
sed -i.bak "/$3/d" ./myresolv.conf
```

It's good to use `-i` with `.bak` to create backup file before overwirting changes.

Comment: Finally someone with an answer that really works. Thanks @jkshah