# Remove a single row from a csv without copying files

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

There are multiple SO questions addressing some form of this topic, but they all seem terribly inefficient for removing only a single row from a csv file (usually they involve copying the entire file). If I have a csv formatted like so:

```
fname,lname,age,sex
John,Doe,28,m
Sarah,Smith,27,f
Xavier,Moore,19,m
```

What is the most efficient way to remove Sarah's row? If possible, I would like to avoid copying the entire file.

Comment: Does this have to be in Python? There are better suited tools.

Comment: I'm open to suggestions, but would prefer to stay within python.

Comment: Agree with kabanus, if this is all you want to do, why not use `sed`/`awk`/`grep`. If you want to do something else, then iterating over the file in Python is probably necessary anyway, so the naive approach is fine.

Comment: BTW you can `open()` with `r+` to read and write to the same file

Comment: Although CSV standard (RFC 4180) does not define an official solution to handle comments, most CSV reading tools offer a way to define a line starting with '#' as a comment. So you may simply replace the first char of your unwanted line with '#', without having to copy the whole file.

Comment: What's the problem you're facing here? is it memory or runtime? if it's memory you can simply do this with `csv` module that returns a generator-like object and `tempfile.TemporaryFile`. Otherwise, as mentioned in previous comments you can use a unix-based command.

Comment: Thanks @Chris_Rands , I didn't know about `r+`, that's helpful. The file is a part of an application that will require reading the file again almost immediately after deleting a row. That application is built in tkinter, which is why I'm looking for a solution of this nature.

Comment: @Kasramvd Runtime. I'd like to access the file immediately afterwards.

Comment: I answered to the best of my knowledge, but perhaps you want these things handled in a cache while your program runs? Once you close you can flush the updated list to the file.

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3/library/mmap.html, specifically the `move` function.

Comment: Can't this be done efficiently (O(1)) in the filesystem by splitting the chunk of the file into two chunks, the second chunk starting at the first block following the line to be deleted, truncating the first chunk to before the line to be deleted, and then appending to the first chunk the portion of the file after the line to be deleted but before the second chunk? Python probably wouldn't have an API to do that though...

Comment: By the way, this is why people put data like this in a database, not a CSV. Just saying...

Comment: @Solomonoff'sSecret That's _theoretically_ possible, but then you're (a) wasting a fair bit of space (sure, that's only one line, but when you offer this ability, _everyone_ will use that and waste lots of space, which can't be reclaimed because of minimum chunk sizes), (b) speeding up disk fragmentation considerably, (c) you need to invent a new way of addressing that can look efficiently at sub-chunk levels. That's not to say it's impossible, but it's more complex than it looks to be at face value, and causes a lot of headaches that make it very much not worth it.

Comment: If you're thinking "but my text editor lets me delete lines without copying", no, your text editor copies too. The copy is just less obvious than if you have to copy manually while writing your own program.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You have a fundamental problem here.  No current filesystem (that I am aware of) provides a facility to remove a bunch of bytes from the middle of a file.  You can overwrite existing bytes, or write a new file.  So, your options are:

- Create a copy of the file without the offending line, delete the old one, and rename the new file in place.  (This is the option you want to avoid).
- Overwrite the bytes of the line with something that will be ignored.  Depending on *exactly* what is going to read the file, a comment character might work, or spaces might work (or possibly even `\0`).  If you want to be completely generic though, this is not an option with CSV files, because there is no defined comment character.
- As a last desperate measure, you could:

  - read up to the line you want to remove
  - read the rest of the file into memory
  - and overwrite the line and all subsequent lines with the data you want to keep.
  - truncate the file as the final position (filesystems usually allow this).

The last option obviously doesn't help much if you are trying to remove the first line (but it is handy if you want to remove a line near the end).  It is also horribly vulnerable to crashing in the middle of the process.

Comment: Thanks this is very helpful. Why exactly is the last option prone to crashing? And is that the method @kabanus is employing in his answer?

Comment: @SamBG It is not *prone* to crashing, but if it does crash during the write (because of a power cut, for example), the results will be catastrophic.  And yes, it is the method that kabanus is using.

Comment: @MartinBonner It's slyness. Most file systems distribute the file volume by clusters that are joined in a doubly linked list. Thus, it is possible to incomplete rewrite of the file during internal insertion / deletion. All databases use this functionality. However, the implementation of such an algorithm, which is stable to failures, is rather laborious. The files that are mapped to the memory some time do this work for you (if the virtual memory manager is smart enough) .

Comment: @SamBG Please, read about https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/mmap.html
URL has an example, that almost cover your case.

Answer (score 4):

Editing files in-place is a task riddled with gotchas (much like modifying an iterable while iterating over it) and usually not worth the trouble. In most cases, writing to a temporary file (or working memory, in dependence of what you have more - storage space or RAM) then deleting the source file and replacing the source file with the temporary file will be equally performant as attempting to do the same thing in-place.

But, if you insist, here's a generalized solution:

```
import os

def remove_line(path, comp):
    with open(path, "r+b") as f:  # open the file in rw mode
        mod_lines = 0  # hold the overwrite offset
        while True:
            last_pos = f.tell()  # keep the last line position
            line = f.readline()  # read the next line
            if not line:  # EOF
                break
            if mod_lines:  # we've already encountered what we search for
                f.seek(last_pos - mod_lines)  # move back to the beginning of the gap
                f.write(line)  # fill the gap with the current line
                f.seek(mod_lines, os.SEEK_CUR)  # move forward til the next line start
            elif comp(line):  # search for our data
                mod_lines = len(line)  # store the offset when found to create a gap
        f.seek(last_pos - mod_lines)  # seek back the extra removed characters
        f.truncate()  # truncate the rest
```

This will remove only the line matching the provided comparison function and then iterate over the rest of the file shifting the data over the 'removed' line. You won't need to load the rest of the file into your working memory, either. To test it, with `test.csv` containing:

```
fname,lname,age,sex
John,Doe,28,m
Sarah,Smith,27,f
Xavier,Moore,19,m
```

You can run it as:

```
remove_line("test.csv", lambda x: x.startswith(b"Sarah"))
```

And you'll get `test.csv` with the in-place removed `Sarah` line:

```
fname,lname,age,sex
John,Doe,28,m
Xavier,Moore,19,m
```

Keep in mind that we're passing a `bytes` comparison function as the file is opened in binary mode to keep consistent line breaks while truncating/overwriting.

**UPDATE**: I was interested in the actual performance of various techniques presented here but I didn't have the time to test them yesterday, so with a bit of a delay I've created a benchmark that could shed some light on it. If you're interested only in the results, scroll all the way down. First I'll explain what was I benchmarking and how I set up the test. I'll also provide all the scripts so you can run the same benchmark at your system.

As for what, I've tested all of the mentioned techniques in this and other answers, namely line replacement using a temporary file (`temp_file_*` functions) and using an in-place editing (`in_place_*`) functions. I have both of those set up in a streaming (reading line by line, `*_stream` functions) and memory (reading the rest of the file in working memory, `*_wm` functions) modes. I've also added an in-place line deletion technique using the `mmap` module (the `in_place_mmap` function). The benchmarked script containing all the functions as well as a small bit of logic to be controlled through the CLI is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import mmap
import os
import shutil
import sys
import time

def get_temporary_path(path):  # use tempfile facilities in production
    folder, filename = os.path.split(path)
    return os.path.join(folder, "~$" + filename)

def temp_file_wm(path, comp):
    path_out = get_temporary_path(path)
    with open(path, "rb") as f_in, open(path_out, "wb") as f_out:
        while True:
            line = f_in.readline()
            if not line:
                break
            if comp(line):
                f_out.write(f_in.read())
                break
            else:
                f_out.write(line)
        f_out.flush()
        os.fsync(f_out.fileno())
    shutil.move(path_out, path)

def temp_file_stream(path, comp):
    path_out = get_temporary_path(path)
    not_found = True  # a flag to stop comparison after the first match, for fairness
    with open(path, "rb") as f_in, open(path_out, "wb") as f_out:
        while True:
            line = f_in.readline()
            if not line:
                break
            if not_found and comp(line):
                continue
            f_out.write(line)
        f_out.flush()
        os.fsync(f_out.fileno())
    shutil.move(path_out, path)

def in_place_wm(path, comp):
    with open(path, "r+b") as f:
        while True:
            last_pos = f.tell()
            line = f.readline()
            if not line:
                break
            if comp(line):
                rest = f.read()
                f.seek(last_pos)
                f.write(rest)
                break
        f.truncate()
        f.flush()
        os.fsync(f.fileno())

def in_place_stream(path, comp):
    with open(path, "r+b") as f:
        mod_lines = 0
        while True:
            last_pos = f.tell()
            line = f.readline()
            if not line:
                break
            if mod_lines:
                f.seek(last_pos - mod_lines)
                f.write(line)
                f.seek(mod_lines, os.SEEK_CUR)
            elif comp(line):
                mod_lines = len(line)
        f.seek(last_pos - mod_lines)
        f.truncate()
        f.flush()
        os.fsync(f.fileno())

def in_place_mmap(path, comp):
    with open(path, "r+b") as f:
        stream = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0)
        total_size = len(stream)
        while True:
            last_pos = stream.tell()
            line = stream.readline()
            if not line:
                break
            if comp(line):
                current_pos = stream.tell()
                stream.move(last_pos, current_pos, total_size - current_pos)
                total_size -= len(line)
                break
        stream.flush()
        stream.close()
        f.truncate(total_size)
        f.flush()
        os.fsync(f.fileno())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) < 3:
        print("Usage: {} target_file.ext <search_string> [function_name]".format(__file__))
        exit(1)
    target_file = sys.argv[1]
    search_func = globals().get(sys.argv[3] if len(sys.argv) > 3 else None, in_place_wm)
    start_time = time.time()
    search_func(target_file, lambda x: x.startswith(sys.argv[2].encode("utf-8")))
    # some info for the test runner...
    print("python_version: " + sys.version.split()[0])
    print("python_time: {:.2f}".format(time.time() - start_time))
```

Next step is to build a tester that will run these functions in as isolated environment as possible, trying to obtain a fair benchmark for each of them. My test is structured as:

- Three sample data CSVs are generated as 1Mx10 matrices (~200MB files) of random numbers with an identifiable line placed at the beginning, middle and the end of them respectively, thus generating test cases for three extreme scenarios.
- The master sample data files are copied as temporary files (since line removal is destructive) before each test.
- Various methods of file syncing and cache clearing are employed to ensure clean buffers before each test starts.
- The tests are run using the highest priority (`chrt -f 99`) through `/usr/bin/time` for benchmark since Python cannot really be trusted to accurately measure its performance in scenarios like these.
- At least three runs of each test are performed to smooth out unpredictable fluctuations.
- The tests are also run in Python 2.7 and Python 3.6 (CPython) to see if there is performance consistency between versions.
- All benchmark data is collected and saved as a CSV for future analysis.

Unfortunately, I didn't have a system at hand where I could run the test fully isolated so my numbers are obtained from running it in a hypervisor. This means that the I/O performance is probably very skewed, but it should similarly affect all the tests still providing comparable data. Either way, you're welcome to run this test on your own system to get results you can relate to.

I've set a test script performing the aforementioned scenario as:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import collections
import os
import random
import shutil
import subprocess
import sys
import time

try:
    range = xrange  # cover Python 2.x
except NameError:
    pass

try:
    DEV_NULL = subprocess.DEVNULL
except AttributeError:
    DEV_NULL = open(os.devnull, "wb")  # cover Python 2.x

SAMPLE_ROWS = 10**6  # 1M lines
TEST_LOOPS = 3
CALL_SCRIPT = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "remove_line.py")  # the above script

def get_temporary_path(path):
    folder, filename = os.path.split(path)
    return os.path.join(folder, "~$" + filename)

def generate_samples(path, data="LINE", rows=10**6, columns=10):  # 1Mx10 default matrix
    sample_beginning = os.path.join(path, "sample_beg.csv")
    sample_middle = os.path.join(path, "sample_mid.csv")
    sample_end = os.path.join(path, "sample_end.csv")
    separator = os.linesep
    middle_row = rows // 2
    with open(sample_beginning, "w") as f_b, \
            open(sample_middle, "w") as f_m, \
            open(sample_end, "w") as f_e:
        f_b.write(data)
        f_b.write(separator)
        for i in range(rows):
            if not i % middle_row:
                f_m.write(data)
                f_m.write(separator)
            for t in (f_b, f_m, f_e):
                t.write(",".join((str(random.random()) for _ in range(columns))))
                t.write(separator)
        f_e.write(data)
        f_e.write(separator)
    return ("beginning", sample_beginning), ("middle", sample_middle), ("end", sample_end)

def normalize_field(field):
    field = field.lower()
    while True:
        s_index = field.find('(')
        e_index = field.find(')')
        if s_index == -1 or e_index == -1:
            break
        field = field[:s_index] + field[e_index + 1:]
    return "_".join(field.split())

def encode_csv_field(field):
    if isinstance(field, (int, float)):
        field = str(field)
    escape = False
    if '"' in field:
        escape = True
        field = field.replace('"', '""')
    elif "," in field or "\n" in field:
        escape = True
    if escape:
        return ('"' + field + '"').encode("utf-8")
    return field.encode("utf-8")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Generating sample data...")
    start_time = time.time()
    samples = generate_samples(os.getcwd(), "REMOVE THIS LINE", SAMPLE_ROWS)
    print("Done, generation took: {:2} seconds.".format(time.time() - start_time))
    print("Beginning tests...")
    search_string = "REMOVE"
    header = None
    results = []
    for f in ("temp_file_stream", "temp_file_wm",
              "in_place_stream", "in_place_wm", "in_place_mmap"):
        for s, path in samples:
            for test in range(TEST_LOOPS):
                result = collections.OrderedDict((("function", f), ("sample", s),
                                                  ("test", test)))
                print("Running {function} test, {sample} #{test}...".format(**result))
                temp_sample = get_temporary_path(path)
                shutil.copy(path, temp_sample)
                print("  Clearing caches...")
                subprocess.call(["sudo", "/usr/bin/sync"], stdout=DEV_NULL)
                with open("/proc/sys/vm/drop_caches", "w") as dc:
                    dc.write("3\n")  # free pagecache, inodes, dentries...
                # you can add more cache clearing/invalidating calls here...
                print("  Removing a line starting with `{}`...".format(search_string))
                out = subprocess.check_output(["sudo", "chrt", "-f", "99",
                                               "/usr/bin/time", "--verbose",
                                               sys.executable, CALL_SCRIPT, temp_sample,
                                               search_string, f], stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
                print("  Cleaning up...")
                os.remove(temp_sample)
                for line in out.decode("utf-8").split("\n"):
                    pair = line.strip().rsplit(": ", 1)
                    if len(pair) >= 2:
                        result[normalize_field(pair[0].strip())] = pair[1].strip()
                results.append(result)
                if not header:  # store the header for later reference
                    header = result.keys()
    print("Cleaning up sample data...")
    for s, path in samples:
        os.remove(path)
    output_file = sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) > 1 else "results.csv"
    output_results = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), output_file)
    print("All tests completed, writing results to: " + output_results)
    with open(output_results, "wb") as f:
        f.write(b",".join(encode_csv_field(k) for k in header) + b"\n")
        for result in results:
            f.write(b",".join(encode_csv_field(v) for v in result.values()) + b"\n")
    print("All done.")
```

---

Finally (and **TL;DR**): here are my results - I'm extracting only best time and memory data from the result set, but you can get the full result sets here: [Python 2.7 Raw Test Data](https://pastebin.com/a8NzZQxV) and [Python 3.6 Raw Test Data](https://pastebin.com/C0dJAi63).

[image: Python File Line Removal - Selected Results]

---

Based on the data I gathered, a couple of final notes:

- If working memory is an issue (working with exceptionally large files etc.), only the `*_stream` functions provide small footprint. On Python 3.x a mid-way would be the `mmap` technique.
- If storage is an issue, only the `in_place_*` functions are viable.
- If both are scarce, the only consistent technique is the `in_place_stream` but at the expense of processing time and increased I/O calls (compared to `*_wm` functions).
- `in_place_*` functions are dangerous as they may lead to data corruption if they are stopped mid-way. `temp_file_*` functions (without integrity checks) are only dangerous on non-transactional file systems.

Comment: Nice solution - but note you're still reading the rest of the file, and writing it. I wonder if truncating gains any run-time advantage if done on a single line or several, like in my solution.

Comment: I'm willing to wager a single write would by faster than multiple, but upvote for creative solution.

Comment: @kabanus - it just avoids reading everything to the working memory (think 10GB files and such), overwriting of the file contents must be performed either way. And, as I've mentioned in the beginning, out of both approaches writing everything to a temp file and then overwriting the old file should be, in theory, the fastest option - if disk space is not an issue.

Comment: Ahh, didn't consider that - correct, this method is much preferable in that case.

Comment: @kabanus - You'd wager correctly ;) I just posted my benchmarks so if you're interested take a look.

Answer (score 3):

This is one way. You do have to load the rest of the file to a buffer, but it's the best I can think of in Python:

```
with open('afile','r+') as fd:
    delLine = 4
    for i in range(delLine):
        pos = fd.tell()
        fd.readline()
    rest = fd.read()
    fd.seek(pos)
    fd.truncate()
    fd.write(rest)
    fd.close()
```

I solved this as if you know the line number. If you want to check the text then instead of the above loop:

```
pos = fd.tell()
while fd.readline().startswith('Sarah'): pos = fd.tell()
```

There will be an exception if 'Sarah' isn't found.

This maybe more efficient if the line you are deleting is nearer to the end, but I'm not sure reading everything, dropping the line, and dumping it back will save much compared to user time (considering this is a Tk app). This also needs only to open and flush once to the file once, so unless files are extremely long, and Sarah is real far down it probably won't be noticeable.

Comment: After reading the other answers, this may be the best any program can do, but I'm unsure.

Comment: You can do in-place editing without reading the rest of the file into the working memory. Check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49734119/7553525). I'm unsure that it would be more efficient than just using a temporary file, tho.

Comment: Note that I've edited this answer to not open the file twice. I have not otherwise verified the algorithm for correctness, though.

Comment: @Robin Thanks, that was a left over from an old copy-paste.

Comment: Check my answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19128876/remove-a-specific-line-from-a-file-without-using-sed-or-awk).  They essentially do the same thing (in tcl and bash (with and without `dd`), with the exception that there is no need to read the rest of the file in one go (potential memory exhaustion).  Instead you only need to read blocks the same size as the line that was deleted.  I think this should easily be doable in python.

Comment: @DigitalTrauma thanks, [zwer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49734119) posted the Python version of a line by line overwrite here as well.

Answer (score 3):

Use sed:

```
sed -ie "/Sahra/d" your_file
```

**Edit**, Sorry I did not fully read all the tags and comments about the need to use python. Either way I would probably try to solve it with some preprocessing using some shell-utility to avoid all that extra code proposed in the other answers. But since I do not fully know your problem it might not be possible?

Good luck!

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: `GNU sed does this by creating a temporary file and sending output to this file rather than to the standard output.`, https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using Pandas. If your data is saved under data.csv, the following should help:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
df = df[df.fname != 'Sarah' ]
df.to_csv('data.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: as long as support for missing integer values is missing, I would take the utmost care with reading and writing back immediately. When the numbers are small, this will not make a large difference, but with numbers that are too large to be exactly represented by `float`, like long ID's for example, this will give you a lot of trouble

Answer (score 1):

> What is the most efficient way to remove Sarah's row? If possible, I would like to avoid copying the entire file.

The most efficient way is to overwrite that row with something that the csv parser ignores. This avoids having to move the rows following the removed one.

If your csv parser can ignore empty lines, overwrite that row with `\n` symbols. Otherwise, if your parser strips whitespace from values, overwrite that row with  (space) symbols.

Comment: I think how to overwrite is the point here. If you can overwrite a line in a file you can just overwrite all of it with `''`, can't you?

Comment: @kabanus Overwrite only a part of the file. seek + write, similar to what your solution does.

Comment: Yup, I was guessing that OP wanted an how-to, but I agree.

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

```
with open("sample.csv",'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('sarah'):continue
        print(line)
```

Comment: isn't this the exact naive approach that the question wants to avoid? Also it's tagged Python 3, `print` is a function